# Mac Python3 Not Working, any idea?

Tags: python, macos

[image]I installed python3 on mac, recently it is not working. I used to run some scripts in terminal using `python3 xxx.py`, however, when I now type in python3, i got

> python3: posix_spawn:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.52.7: No
>   such file or directory

I did not delete the default python installed.

Comment: I thin there is a typo in the link: probably it should be `python3.5.2.7`. Python 3.52 does not exists.

Comment: What happens if you type `whereis python3`?

Comment: Or better yet `hash -r python3`

Comment: try steps in http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/osx/

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem nothing happened after typing

Comment: Exactly how did you install python3? Did you use a package manager like HomeBrew or did you download the .pkg from Python.org? I'm guessing your most easy way out might be to re-install it.

Comment: Please add the output of `echo $PATH` to your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you install python3 using homebrew? I had the same issue, and it was cause by a symlink error. Following this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2xa5xc/how_would_i_fix_this_path_issue/

I was able to fix it.. Simply just ran:

```
brew link --overwrite python3
```

And my issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

[Avery's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45002666/2873060) (below command) did not work for me:

```
brew link --overwrite python3
```

**Permanent fix**:

> Removed unnecessary export path in ~/.bash_profile

Steps taken:

1. After searching a little more about the problem I found that this might have been caused because I installed another python3 (other than brew) instance through .dmg file downloaded from the python website.
2. I had already run brew doctor, brew prune, and brew unlink && brew link for python (python 2) and python3, so most of the cleaning had already been done.
3. I tried alias python3 which returned: -bash: alias: python3: not found
4. I went to the ~/.bash_profile to add "alias python='python3'" when I noticed there was another export PATH to python3. *Upon removing that unnecessary statement the problem was solved without the need for reinstalling or exporting path.*

**Temporary fix** (lasted one terminal Instance):
Reinstall python3 using home brew and exported path:

```
brew reinstall python
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and the below command also worked for me:

```
brew link -- overwrite python3
```